# boost shared_ptr use with default constructor

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

I think I might need to do something like the following pseudo-code in my application:

```
boost::shared_ptr<T> p;
...
...
p = boost::shared_ptr<T>(new T);
```

I realize there are other options for using the assignment operator, but I noticed in the `boost::shared_ptr` documentation/example that they never discussed a case like this one involving the default constructor.

My question I suppose, is: is this valid use? In other words, is it legal and could it lead to potential memory leaks? Appreciate any ideas/corrections. Thanks much!

NOTE: I do recall reading, as also some comments below suggest, that they recommend to always use a named `shared_ptr` when invoking the constructor with `new`. Still, I find it hard to imagine this might cause any harm. Kindly post any counter-examples if you have them. Thanks!

Comment: This violates the #1 rule of using smart pointers safely:  ["always use a named smart pointer variable to hold the result of new."](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) (The code as is _appears_ safe to me because the `operator=` is specified as non-throwing.  However, it's best to follow this best practice _all the time._  It's good to develop good habits and it helps you not to have to worry about whether or not your code is safe or not.)

Comment: Yes, I remember that comment in the docs.. hence the question. Seems innocuous enough though. How could this break anything?

Comment: @squashed.bugaboo : It's less about being able to break anything, and more about being idiomatic and unsurprising.

Comment: I don't know what it could break.  I have limited brainpower; following that best practice helps me not to waste it.

Comment: Thanks @James/ildjarn: Good one, James :-) Will try and follow that, but I think I'll have to re-work the code a bit to accommodate the dictum and I'm debating whether that is really necessary. Thanks, again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is perfectly legal and memory safe.  The fact that you are invoking the default constructor on `T` is irrelevant: as long as you have a dynamically allocated object, you can wrap it in a `shared_ptr<>`

If you refer to the default constructor of `shared_ptr<>` that's fine too: the wrapped pointer is NULL, which will not be deleted when the other `shared_ptr<>` is assigned

You will have to be careful, though to check whether the contents are NULL or not, otherwise you might be accessing an invalid pointer

Comment: I've selected this as the answer since I've tried it and it works for me and all hell didn't break loose. But I'd like to acknowledge the caveat that it violates the recommendation attached with using shared_ptr. Thanks.